# Group $ GL(V) $ acts naturally on $ \mathscr{F} $, how to get its orbits?

Tags: group-actions

[image: screenshot]

Could you please explain to me the meaning of the marking? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is basics of flag varieties.

$GL(V)$ acts transitively on each set of flags $V_1 \subset \dots \subset V_n$ where the dimensions of the subspaces $V_i$ are fixed (this is basic linear algebra).

Equivalently, we can describe the dimensions of the subspaces $V_i$ by giving $dim V_1$ and the dimensions of the quotient vector spaces $V_{i+1}/V_i$ (which is simply $dim V_{i+1} - dim V_i$.

Answer (score 1):

What it is saying is that if you have two flags 
$$
f=(V_1\subset\cdots\subset V_n)\quad\text{and}\quad g=(W_1\subset\cdots\subset W_n)
$$ 
in $\cal F$, you can find $g\in{\rm GL}(V)$ such that 
$$
g(V_i)=W_i\quad\text{for all}\quad i=1,...,n
$$ 
if and only if
$$
\dim(V_{i+1}/V_i)=\dim(W_{i+1}/W_i)\quad\text{for all}\quad i=1,...,n.
$$

Comment: Of course, you also need to know $dim V_1$ (or one of the other dimensions) for this statement to be true.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward: since $\dim V_n=\dim W_n=\dim V=d$ that comes for free, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks! If I replace $\mathscr{F}$ with $\mathscr{SF}$(super flag varieties),  $GL(V)$ with $GL(p|q)$, what will it become?

Comment: Sorry, it means $\Theta_d$($GL(p|q)/\mathscr{SF}\times \mathscr{SF}$).

Comment: "it" means $\Theta_d$($GL(p|q)/\mathscr{SF}\times \mathscr{SF}$).

Comment: @AndreaMori good point.